# My variable is not incrementing inside my JS function JSX

Tags: html, reactjs, dom, jsx

got a slight issue within my JSX function, the variable I is not incrementing, only returning 1 to the console.

```
function newTask() {
    var i = 0;
    i+=1; //or i++
    console.log(i);

    if(i == 1) {
        class NewTask extends React.Component {
            render() {
                return (<div class="new-task">True</div>);
            }
        }
        ReactDOM.render(<NewTask/>, document.getElementById('forms'));

    }
    else if(i == 2) {
        class NewTask extends React.Component {
            render() {
                return (document.body.getElementById('new-task'));
            }
        }
        ReactDOM.render(<NewTask/>, document.getElementById('forms'));
    }
}
```

Thanks for any constructive feedback :)

Comment: Are you trying to call `newTask` multiple times?

Comment: It is always set to 0 and then incremented once, how would it ever go above zero?

Comment: I have a script that calls this newTask function via a button event, I then want this function to increment so if the user clicks once it shows the dom, if the user clicks again it removes it from the dom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are initialising the variable `i` inside the function `newTask`.

So, every time you call it, `i` is initialised to 0 and then incremented to 1.

What you want is a global variable and you can achieve that by moving the declaration of variable `i` outside of the function.

```
var i = 0;

function newTask() {
  i += 1; //or i++
  console.log(i);

  if (i == 1) {
    class NewTask extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return <div class="new-task">True</div>;
      }
    }
    ReactDOM.render(<NewTask />, document.getElementById("forms"));
  } else if (i == 2) {
    class NewTask extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return document.body.getElementById("new-task");
      }
    }
    ReactDOM.render(<NewTask />, document.getElementById("forms"));
  }
}
```

Comment: That was what I was looking for, didn't realise it needed to be a global variable, many thanks! ^-^